# How to check visibility for multiselect person field for feedback icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

HR list schema

HRname  vacancy   Panelmembers         Status

John     Job1      Joy;Josesph;Smith    processconclusion

[image]

My query is when HR modify status Processconclusion and he enter Panelmembers names while modifying the status using PowerApps edit form ,after that the feedback icon should be visible to the panelmembers names Joy,Joseph,Smith so that they will submit feedback newform

4.1.    Once a HRselection process has been finalized, HR will change status as "Process Concluded” .A notification will be sent to the HR and the rest of the selection panel members to fill the survey and provide feedback on the selection process.

4.2.    The following fields will be displayed in the form to be filled to provide feedback on the selection process:

4.2.1.  Do you think that is useful etc?

4.3.    When feedback is submitted, the information will be available for both HR and Panelteam members. Some specific fields will be specific for HR

4.4.    When feedback is submitted, the data sent will not be editable anymore by any user.

4.5.    5 days after the moment HR pressed the “Selection Process Concluded” ,the survey will be closed and the rest of the Selection Panel members will not be able to fill feedback form anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/Hide icon/button based on if current user is part of multiple selection person or group column in SharePoint, you can use formula like below in `Visible` property of icon/button control:

```
User().Email in ThisItem.PanelMembers.Email
```

Where `ThisItem.PanelMembers` will be current context/value of multiple selection person or group column. You can adjust this part in formula and use correct column context/value.